# Why we put CSS transition in enter-active instead of enter when using react-transition-group?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I read the document about React Transition, I noticed that they usually put CSS transition parts in enter-active and exit-active class instead of in enter and exit class.

```js
function App() {
  const [inProp, setInProp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <CSSTransition in={inProp} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
        <div>
          {"I'll receive my-node-* classes"}
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setInProp(true)}>
        Click to Enter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.my-node-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-node-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.my-node-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-node-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What I mean is, in code the part that determine how long before the content appear is determine in `timeout` property of `CSSTransition`, not in CSS. This also true to how long before the content completely disappear. So my first question is why transition-duration need to be set?

Another question I asked is how the transition parts is kicked in. In the document it said that in entering state the component will first render `.my-node-enter` before `.my-node-enter-active`. As I learn, CSS transition defined what will happen if the CSS property change **after** the transition property is defined. So in this case, the transition part would be useless as they is placed after the component is entering, and nothing would happen after the component finish entering (I keep simple that we only consider enter and exit state).

However when I tried to remove that transition part

```css
.my-node-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-node-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-node-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-node-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The content appears and disappear almost immediately, which is strange as there should be a delay due to `timeout` which still set to 200. And I don't know why the `transition` kick in here.

Can somebody explain me why?